# How are computed Branching decay modes (for Higgs boson and from a general point of view)

Tags: nuclear-physics, higgs, bosons

I would like to know how are computed the branching decay diagram, like for example with Higgs boson represented below ([source](http://www.planetastronomy.com/special/2014-special/11sep/Sirois-SAF.htm)):

[image: Higgs branching]

It seems there are 5 ways of decays for Higgs boson.

I suppose there are theorical calculus behind this diagram but concretely, what are the origins and the hypothesis to get these curves ?

Are cross sections implied into these calculus ?

Comment: In general, the answer to your question is quantum field theory (the theoretical framework for modern particle physics) and Feynman diagrams. If you want more detail, definitely consult a textbook on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In quantum field theory, **branching ratio**s are calculated as the ratio between the **decay width** of a specific decay process and the total decay width of the particle.

For instance, for the decay of K-short meson into charged pions,
$$\mathrm{BR}(K \rightarrow \pi^+ \pi^-) = \frac{\Gamma (K_S \rightarrow \pi^+ \pi^-)}{\Gamma (K_S)}$$
where the total decay width is $\Gamma (K_S)=\Gamma (K_S \rightarrow \pi^+ \pi^-)+\Gamma (K_S \rightarrow \pi^0 \pi^0)$. (Here, I have given K-short as an example because it has only two decay modes which makes it easy to talk about. I could write the complete list of the Higgs decays but it would just make the answer more crowded. See for example the [Particle Data Group's booklet](http://pdg.lbl.gov) for all decay modes of all particles)

In order to calculate the **decay width**, you need to calculate the matrix element, $\mathcal{M}$, for the process in question, which is done by applying Feynman rules of the model on that process. For more details, you need to refer to a quantum field theory textbook, e.g., Griffiths or Peskin/Schröder.

The plot in your question is calculated for different Higgs masses since the ratios depend on the Higgs mass which is a free parameter of the Standard Model. Apparently plot is shown in order to say that the discovery of the boson with a mass of 125 GeV at the LHC in 2012 has the same branching ratios for the Higgs boson in the Standard Model.

Comment: great ! I will remenber it : QFT and Feynman diagrams allow to compute these branching ratio. Regards